# Why does this hysteresis curve approach saturation so immediately?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, dc, oscilloscope, hysteresis

I am trying to find out the hysteresis curve of a transformer iron core. I use an LM741 for the op-amp integrator.

As I increase my 50Hz input voltage, I observe that Vin (value on the x-axis) does increase, while Vout (on the y-axis) increases very little. This does look like it is getting saturated, but I haven't seen the "linear region" on a B-H curve.

To find out why, I measured some data points, calculated B, H, and permeability with my other data, and plotted B vs H and permeability vs H. The left part of the graph is different from what it theoretically should be.

Theoretically, there should be a curve at the beginning(shown in the 3rd picture), which contains a section with a linear B-H relationship, but my B values are already so high at the very beginning.

I suspect that it's because Vout value also reflects the +-9v DC supply voltage for the opamp. I suspect this, because as I increased the DC supply, Vout increased too, which increased the height of the hysteresis curve.(just for testing, The DC supply was constantly +-9v in other times)

This makes the y-axis value already pretty high when my input voltage was only 0.02116v. Every time as I only increase a little Vin, this causes little Vout change. Thus, negligible changes on the y-axis are observed.

The iron core can't saturate already at 0.02116v, right? It approaches saturation so fast that it seems wrong. My measured permeability doesn't have a trend line at the beginning that leads up to its maximum point.

Am I just thinking too much or is something wrong?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: 9]

Comment: magnetic materials can be made to saturate very fast ( have very high permeability). Whether this is the case for your core is a little unclear to me? what do you mean with 0.02 V ? Volt is not a unit related to core saturation..What is the magnetic field (in Oe or A/m) that you apply ? A schematic instead of your last image would greatly help with understanding.

Comment: When you run out of magnetic domains to flip, you simply run out. Then it's no different than an air core.

Comment: @tobalt I replaced the last image with a schematic

Comment: @tobalt with 0.02V I meant what is measured by the oscilloscope's channel 1. It measures the AC voltage input that I fed in. I used it to measure the field strength H through ampere's law, H=NI/L. Thus the H is 3.7A/m. Is this a reasonable number at which a core could saturate?

Comment: that is far less than earths magnetic field. So: no. I suppose that you calculated it maybe wrong ? L would be the coil radius approximately

Comment: As in your duplicate question, are you sure it's the transformer not the opamp that's saturating?

Comment: @user_1818839 If it saturates, then the output voltage should be clipped. But Vout, which is the yellow signal, is like a square wave, right? So it is not clipped I think?

Comment: Clipped signals look a lot like square waves...

Comment: @user_1818839 The hysteresis curve got pretty distorted already when AC Vinput was 1v.  I did measure the Vout across the opamp output terminal, and it was around 3.8v and it slowly increased as I increased Vin. Thus, it can't be saturated, right?

Comment: @tobalt L is the effective length, so I took the longest and the shortest length around the core type transformer core, and then divided it by 2. I got 0.345m. Maybe the opamp got saturated?

Comment: The wiring looks strange. Are you sure that you are measuring I (current), on your scope ( channel 1) ?

Comment: @Antonio51 I am not measuring I, I am measuring Vin, the input AC voltage, because in XY mode, it's a voltage signal versus another voltage signal... I did add a resistor so that I can calculate current. I think they serve the same purpose, right?

Comment: The voltage on Rin is proportional to current, yes. Thus to H=N*i/L.

Comment: @Antonio51 Thank you! I hope the wiring doesn't looks strange anymore ;D I wonder are there any other strange/ not suitable values from the circuit schematic?

Comment: Not sure what the op amp is for.  Why not try removing C3 and Rin and the op amp circuit and putting the 10K right across the secondary, and using the scope probes to measure Vin and Vout directly.  You can imply primary current from the secondary current through the 10K.  In your photos, the third X-Y scope figure clearly shows saturation, but the first two don't.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Thank you very much. However, I tried it and it didn't work out.. An opamp is needed because it acts as an integrator here. the voltage output from the secondary winding is the rate of change of flux. The opamp integrates this signal into flux over the entire time, which gives the output voltage and allows me to calculate B, the magnetic field density...

Comment: The voltage on Rin is proportional to current. Thus to H=N*i/L. And should be Channel1.

Comment: Try searching for Magnetics' catalog of tape wounds, or Ferroxcube's ferrite catalog, and browse through them to see how various B-H loops can be. You'll find that some of them can be squarish, while others will be softer.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thank you! this helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple suggestions here.  I would measure both V and I on the same side of the transformer. B=uH.

Measure B=Integral(Vprimary*dt)/(Nturns*Acore)

Measure H=Nturns*Iprimary/Lcore.  Measuring Iprimary could be done with a current probe or a shunt resistor.  Make sure you don’t accidently short out your shunt through the scope chassis.

Use your scope to divide B/H to get u or plot them both in XY mode.  Nturns, Acore, and Lcore are all constants.  You may also have correct for gains of your current probe and voltage integrator but these are constants too assuming a fixed test frequency.

Also, the 741 isn’t very suitable as an integrator due to its relatively large voltage offset and input bias currents.  Even with no input signal, these dc offsets will cause the 0.1uF capacitor to quickly integrate into saturation.  Ex 80nA = I input bias = C dV/dt = 0.1uF dV/dt  => dV/dt = 800mV/sec.  This could be mitigated somewhat by using a bigger capacitor.  I would also add a switch to short the capacitor through a 100 ohm resistor to reset the integrator to 0V.  A more precise op amp would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wonder why do we need to reset the integrator to 0V? And does it mean to reset the output voltage to 0 every time?

Comment: The integrator must be reset because the op amp is not ideal.  It has DC offsets in both input current and voltage that will get integrated by the capacitor and cause the integrator output to drift.   If the dc offsets are small and the capacitor is big, the drift might be slow enough that you can ignore it.  Just push the reset switch at the beginning of your test.  If you're interested in how to reduce amplifier dc errors, look up chopper stabilized amplifiers.

Comment: We do have mathjax here; it would be so much easier to read your equations if you used it.

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much, I will definitely look into it and improve the integrator. I am a bit unsure about what you meant by "Ex 80nA" ,could you please clarify that a bit? Thank you!

Comment: Ideally, no current should flow into op amp inputs but a little bit flows in real parts. This is called Input Bias on the datasheet (80nA on the 741 that I saw).  It varies a lot over different models, parts and temperature.

That bias must be supplied form somewhere.  Imagine shorting the integrator input R to +In.  The op amp changes its output so that -In equals + In.  If the 80nA is supplied through the10k, +In and -In differ by 800uV and the op amp is not settled.  Instead, the current is supplied through the feedback path.  If it was only a cap, it would integrate as I=Cdv/dt.

Comment: The 1 Meg resistor is a good idea and helps rein in the runaway integrator.  80nA*1Meg = 80mV

Also, +In is supposed to equal -In in steady state.  In reality there's an offset - 1mV typ in the 741.  1mV*(1Meg/10k + 1) = 101mV offset at the output.

All these values are typical and could be much higher in the worst case.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the C2/C3 divider is.  Their impedance is quite high for a 50/60Hz stimulus, making the currents small and hard to measure.  It might be simpler to drive the transformer directly from the AC source.  Lastly, double check your current measurement connections on channel 1.  You must measure across the resistor, not the coil to get current.

Comment: Thank you. I did originally drive the transformer directly from the AC source, but then found out that the hysteresis curve was highly saturated already when input =1v. thus I thought the AC voltage input must be too high, so I added the C2/C3 divider.

Comment: But then I realized that it might not be the transformer that was saturated - it might be the opamp that was saturated (the output signal, the yellow one, looks like it got clipped). The reason might be that the opamp gain was too high - 1M/10k is A LOT! Also, to properly integrate the opamp signal, the input signal's frequency(50Hz) of the should be at least 10 times the cut-off frequency, right? Therefore, if I decrease R1 so that the gain smaller than 5, then I expect the opamp will be no longer saturated....is my idea correct though?

Comment: Ignoring the 1Meg, the gain of the integrator at a given frequency is 1/(2 * pi* j * f * Rin * C) or about 3.2 at 50Hz for Rin = 10k and C = 0.1uF.  That seems reasonable to me without any changes for an input signal of 1 volt.  The 1Meg resistor limits the DC gain to 1Meg/10k = 100 – also pretty reasonable as long there isn’t much DC in the stimulus.

Not sure what you are defining as the cutoff frequency.  It might be good to post an updated schematic showing present component values, corrections to current measurement probes, moving voltage measurement to the primary side and results.

Comment: @Mark thank you very much. I am a bit confused about " Ex 80nA = I input bias = C dV/dt = 0.1uF dV/dt => dV/dt = 800mV/sec." from your answer. Is this the rate at which the op-amp gets saturated? It would be much appreciated if you could explain a bit..